# Can I shrink my Windows 10 display to be about 1/4" shorter in height while still retaining the same screen resolution?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Like many people, I have transitioned to a WFH environment for a couple months. As a software developer, I simply VPN into our network and use Remote Desktop to remotely take control over my Windows 10 desktop at work containing my entire work environment.

The problem is that RDP by design has a narrow yet long bar that takes up about 1/4 of the top 1/4" of my screen. This bar is in the way when working with Chrome and other programs, and I constantly find myself either moving the bar or adjusting the window sizes of other programs so I can more easily click on buttons and tabs hidden below the bar.

I'm wondering whether I can configure my Windows 10 desktop at work in such a way that it in effect doesn't use that top 1/4", without the RDP bar lowering as well. That way, I don't need to constantly move that RDP bar from side to side (which often causes me to accidentally shrink the RDP window because I drag it slightly too low).

Comment: Could you just not display the RDP bar at all?  See [How to Hide the Remote Desktop Bar](https://precisioninfinity.com/nerd-is-the-new-jock/tech-news-and-rumors/hide-or-show-remote-desktop-bar/)

Comment: Put the RDP session in a Window and then size the Window to precisely the size you want. This works for me using Windows RDP